# How do I create a user for a server process I want to install on MacOS 10.6?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts, osx-leopard

In MacOS < 10.5, the NetInfo Manager let you see and manage accounts that weren't full users, i.e. couldn't log in. That app is gone, leaving me only with dscl :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://diymacserver.com/2007/11/06/daemon-user-creation-changed-in-leopard/) (For Leopard) says that you can use dscl or get the [Server Admin Tools](http://www.apple.com/support/downloads/serveradmintools105.html) from Apple ([here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL914)'s the version for 10.6).

Use the **Workgroup Manager** and hit cancel in the Connect dialog and acknowledge the warnings that you're working on a local DB. In 10.6, you don't cancel, just put in localhost as the server and your admin credentials. Then you can use a GUI to manage users like you did in the NetInfo app.

Answer (score 0):

In 10.6, the Accounts prefpane lets you create "Sharing Only" accounts. I believe this will do what you want.